# How to find open port and tunnel traffic through it to bypass firewall

Tags: networking, firewall

I want to bypass firewall on my network. So I want to know how I can find open ports on the firewall and tunnel all my traffic through it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nmap to check what port's are open.
If you are using linux,

apt-get install nmap
then
nmap localhost or IP that you want check it

Comment: can you tell how to tunnel the traffic through the port found in nmap